# Opengl 4.3: Using One SSBO Object in Vertex & Fragment Shader

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl

I've been trying to Use Shader Storage Buffer Objects(SSBO) with opengl 4.3 core for some time but cant even get my Shader Program To Link

Here is the Code For My Vertex Shader

```
# version 430 core

in vec3 vertex;
uniform mat4
perspectiveMatrix,
viewMatrix,
modelMatrix;

in vec3 normal;
out vec3 lightVectors[3];
out vec3 vertexNormal;
out vec3 cameraVector;

layout(std430,binding=1)buffer Lights
{
  vec3 positions[3];
  vec3 attenuations[3];
  vec3 colors[3];
}buf1;

void main()
{
 vec4 worldVertex=modelMatrix*vec4(vertex,1.0);
 gl_Position=perspectiveMatrix*viewMatrix*worldVertex;

 vertexNormal=(modelMatrix*vec4(normal,0)).xyz;
 for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
  lightVectors[i]=buf1.positions[i]-worldVertex.xyz;
 }
 cameraVector=(inverse(viewMatrix)*vec4(0,0,0,1)).xyz-worldVertex.xyz;

}
```

And Here Is The Code for My Fragment Shader

```
# version 430 core

in vec3 vertexNormal;
in vec3 cameraVector;
in vec3 lightVectors[3];

out vec4 pixelColor;

layout(std430,binding=1)buffer Lights
{
  vec3 positions[3];
  vec3 attenuations[3];
  vec3 colors[3];
}buf2;

uniform Material
{
 vec3 diffuseMat;
 vec3 specularMat;
 float reflectivity;
 float shininess;
};

float getAtten(int i)
{
 float l=length(lightVectors[i]); 
 float atten=(buf2.attenuations[i].x*l)
 +((buf2.attenuations[i].y)*(l*l))
 +((buf2.attenuations[i].z)*(l*l*l));
 return atten;
}

vec3 computeLightColor()
{
 vec3 unitNormal=normalize(vertexNormal);
 vec3 unitCam=normalize(cameraVector);

 vec3 diffuse,specular,lightColor;
 for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
 {
 vec3 unitLight=normalize(lightVectors[i]);
 float atten=getAtten(i);

 float nDiffuseDot=dot(unitLight,unitNormal);
 float diffuseIntencity=max(0,nDiffuseDot); 
 diffuse+=(buf2.colors[i]*diffuseMat*diffuseIntencity)/atten;

 vec3 reflectedLight=reflect(-unitLight,unitNormal); 
 float nSpecularDot=dot(reflectedLight,unitCam);
 float specularIntencity=pow(max(0,nSpecularDot),reflectivity)*shininess;
 specular+=(buf2.colors[i]*specularMat*specularIntencity)/atten;
 }
 lightColor=diffuse+specular;

 return lightColor;
}

void main()
{
 pixelColor=vec4(computeLightColor(),1)*0.7;
}
```

The Code common to both These Shaders is

```
layout(std430,binding=1)buffer Lights
{
  vec3 positions[3];
  vec3 attenuations[3];
  vec3 colors[3];
};
```

This is an SSBO I'm using for my Lighting Calculations

I need to use this one single buffer in both Vertex & Fragment Shader because in my Vertex Shader This part of code

```
lightVectors[i]=buf1.positions[i]-worldVertex.xyz;
```

Uses The Light Positions defined in The SSBO

And in the Fragment Shader the

```
float getAtten(i) and
vec3 computeLight()
```

Method Uses the buffers colors[3] and attenuations[3] "Arrays" to compute diffuse and specular components

But i cannot Link The Vertex & Fragement Shader using the above SSBO Definition
And The Shader Info Log is empty So I don't know the error either

Is There A Way to Use The Above Defined SSBO In both the Vertex And Fragement Shader Without Creating 2 Separate SSBO i.e one for Vertex Shader And One for fragement Shader?

This Is My Shader Class. All My Shaders Extends To This Class For Implementation

```
public abstract class StaticShader extends Shader3D
{
 private int      
 vertexShaderID=-1,
 fragmentShaderID=-1;

 private boolean alive=false;
 private boolean isActive=false;

 public StaticShader(Object vertexShader,Object fragmentShader)
 {
   programID=GL20.glCreateProgram();  
   vertexShaderID=loadShader(vertexShader,GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
   fragmentShaderID=loadShader(fragmentShader,GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

   GL20.glAttachShader(programID,vertexShaderID);
   GL20.glAttachShader(programID,fragmentShaderID);
   bindAttributes();

   activateShader();
  }

 private int loadShader(Object src,int shaderType)
 {
     StringBuilder source=super.loadSource(src);

     int shaderID=GL20.glCreateShader(shaderType);
     GL20.glShaderSource(shaderID,source);
     GL20.glCompileShader(shaderID);

     if(GL20.glGetShaderi(shaderID,GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS)==GL11.GL_FALSE)
     {
       infoLogSize=GL20.glGetShaderi(shaderID,GL20.GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH);
       System.err.println(GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID,infoLogSize));
       System.err.println("COULD NOT COMPILE SHADER");
       System.exit(-1);
     }    

     return shaderID;
 }

protected void activateShader()
 {   
  GL20.glLinkProgram(programID);
  if(GL20.glGetProgrami(programID,GL20.GL_LINK_STATUS)==GL11.GL_FALSE)
  {  
    infoLogSize=GL20.glGetProgrami(programID,GL20.GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH);
    System.err.println(GL20.glGetProgramInfoLog(programID,infoLogSize));
    System.err.println("COULD NOT LINK SHADER");
    System.exit(-1);
  } 

  GL20.glValidateProgram(programID); 
  if(GL20.glGetProgrami(programID,GL20.GL_VALIDATE_STATUS)==GL11.GL_FALSE)
  {
    infoLogSize=GL20.glGetProgrami(programID,GL20.GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH);  
    System.err.println(GL20.glGetProgramInfoLog(programID,infoLogSize));
    System.err.println("COULD NOT VALIDATE SHADER");
    System.exit(-1);
  } 
 }

 public void dispose()
 {   
    GL20.glUseProgram(0);

    GL20.glDetachShader(programID,vertexShaderID);
    GL20.glDetachShader(programID,fragmentShaderID);

    GL20.glDeleteShader(vertexShaderID);
    GL20.glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderID);

    GL20.glDeleteProgram(programID);
 }        
}
```

I'm Using LWJGL 2.9.3 Java Opengl Version

The program compiles fine but glLinkprogram ()
return false and the shader info log is empty

I haven't even created any buffer object of any sort I'm just learning the syntax at the moment

Any help will  be greatly appreciated thank u in advance and to those who have helped me in the comments but I'm greatly frustrated at the moment

Comment: Yes, this is possible. It is very unlikely that the linker info log is empty when linking fails, so you might want to start with looking into that (or showing the code here).

Comment: The Shader Code given above Ihas always printed Compile/Linking Errors and exits the application when it does I hope this helps

Comment: For those coming from google looking for a simple solution on how to initialize a SSBO, it works exactly like UBO, except that you change `GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER` to `GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER`. The shader code is also the same except `std430` and `buffer` instead of `std140` and `uniform`. There is not much stuff out there for SSBOs but plenty of learning material on UBOs.

Answer (score 2):

In youre code I get the linker error:

> error: binding mismatch between shaders for SSBO (named Lights)

You have to use the same binding point for equal named buffer objects in the different shader stages.

In your vertex shader:

```
layout(std430, binding=1) buffer Lights
{
  vec3 positions[3];
  vec3 attenuations[3];
  vec3 colors[3];
} buf1;
```

`Lights` ist the  externally visible name of the buffer and `buf1` is the name of the block within the shader.

This means you have to use the same binding point for the buffer object `Lights` in the fragment shader:

```
layout(std430,binding=1) buffer Lights // <---- binding=1 instead of binding=2
{
    vec3 positions[3];
    vec3 attenuations[3];
    vec3 colors[3];
}buf2;
```

See also:

- [OpenGL Shading Language 4.6 specification - 4.3.7 Buffer Variables](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf)

> The buffer qualifier is used to declare global variables whose values are stored in the data store of a
>   buffer object bound through the OpenGL API.
>
> ```
>  // use buffer to create a buffer block (shader storage block)
>  buffer BufferName { // externally visible name of buffer
>      int count; // typed, shared memory...
>      ... // ...
>      vec4 v[]; // last member may be an array that is not sized
>                // until after link time (dynamically sized)
>  } Name; // name of block within the shader
> ```

- [OpenGL Shading Language 4.6 specification - 4.4.5 Uniform and Shader Storage Block Layout Qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf)

Comment: You Were Right It did show The Binding Mismatch error I didn't see it properly my bad.but Now When I Run The Program The Info Log Is For Real Empty. I'm gonna update my question Thanks for the Tip But Still Nothing Is Working

Comment: Also I have not used any buffer object just the shader code. No buffer have been created and used im just learning the syntax at the moment. The program crashes at the linking phase